# How to increase clickable area of an element without increasing its padding?

Tags: html, css

I have created an unordered list and styled it accordingly using CSS in order to achieve the following Customer Testimonial Selectors:

[image]

Everything seems to be fine except one thing - when I view my webpage on mobile phone these selectors are very hard to click on (you have to click them very very precisely in order to select the second testimonial).

I've tried increasing padding on the element, however it would not work for me because increasing the padding automatically increases the size of the actual selector element... Here is my html & css:

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 text-center indent-bottom">
 <ul>
   <li id="client-1-selector" class="client-selector active-client"></li>
   <li id="client-2-selector" class="client-selector"></li>
   <li id="client-3-selector" class="client-selector"></li>
   <li id="client-3-selector" class="client-selector"></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.client-selector {
    cursor: pointer;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    background-color: #D9D9D9;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.client-selector:not(:last-child) {
    margin-right: 14px;
}

.active-client {
    background-color: #E48210;
}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using pseudo elements you can do it:

For instance:

```
.element { 
    position:relative; 
}
.element:after {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    top:-10px; bottom:-10px; 
    left:-10px; right:-10px; 
}
```

By adding a pseudo element like `:after` you can increase the amount of space an element takes, which in consecuence increase the space that this element takes so you can click in a wider space of this element.

- [Here](http://front-back.com/expand-clickable-areas-for-a-better-touch-experience) is an article explaining about the details.

As advice:

> This technique works IE8+

Comment: Thanks, for the article, much appreciated. It worked ;)

Answer (score 11):

Try something like this:

```
.client-selector { position: relative; }
.client-selector::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
     top: -50%;
    left: -50%;
     width: 200%;
    height: 200%;
}
```

This will put an `::after` pseudo-element around your `.client-selector` elements that is twice the width and height.

Answer (score 0):

With sx-props, you can do it like this:

```
sx = {{
    position: 'fixed',
    '&:after': {
      content: '""',
      position: 'absolute',
      top: '-10px',
      bottom: '-10px',
      left: '-10px',
      right: '-10px',
    },
  }}
```